# Golang convert UTF16 string to UTF8

Tags: go, utf-8, utf-16

I'm building a map of emoji unified unicode characters to their common names. I have strings representing each emoji, in UTF16 format. For example, the string "00A9" represents the copyright symbol. I need to convert that into a utf8 rune, so I can compare it to input I receive from the user, but I haven't found the right incantation of the hex/utf16/utf8 packages to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parse](https://godoc.org/strconv#ParseInt) the hex string as an integer. Use a [string conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type) to convert the integer to UTF-8.

```
n, err := strconv.ParseInt("00A9", 16, 32)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
s := string(rune(n))
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/9rZRnYwXPVH)

Answer (score 0):

you can try lib: [codepage detect](https://github.com/softlandia/cpd)

```
s := "..."
s = cpd.DecodeUTF16be(s)
s = cpd.DecodeUTF16le(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are unicode packages in Go

- https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf16/
- https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/